# Is there a way to share app link playstore with data and get it when the app is download in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to share my app with an affiliate code and when a user click the link, he will be redirected to playstore or appstore. I want to know if it's possible to get the affiliate code when the user install the application ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get Code by using UTM Params in URL

- Create a URL & Add Affiliate Code as Parameter in URL
- When User open the URL, redirect user to PlayStore / AppStore

You can refer to this [article](https://medium.com/7span/how-to-handle-utm-params-in-flutter-android-3d19c888b600) for more detailed information on How to UTM Params?